# Как взаимодействовать с DOM в шаблоне Mustache?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Можно ли взаимодействовать с тегами внутри шаблона mustache, те добавлять их в переменные, писать для них обработчики событий и тд ?

как пример я добавил в шаблон ссылку (#test-link), но через js обратиться к ней не получается

```js
function renderHello() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { name: 'Luke' });
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}

const testLink = document.querySelector('#test-link');
console.log(testLink)
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="renderHello()">
    <div id="target">Loading...</div>
    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
      Hello {{ name }}!
      <a href="#" id="test-link">test link</a>
    </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@latest"></script>
    <script src="render.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Из шаблона - нет, взаимодействовать нельзя, шаблон-то рендерится в строку, а не в DOM. А снаружи - почему это может вдруг не получиться?

Comment: а как снаружи ? с темплейтом получается я тоже не могу взаимодействовать

Comment: Однако, рекомендую срочно выбросить этот ужас нафиг пока не нахватались XSS и перейти на более безопасные технологии, такие как [lit-html](https://lit.dev/docs/libraries/standalone-templates/)

Comment: так-то вы всё делаете правильно, только почему-то забываете какой id присвоили ссылке

Comment: Почему вы создали `а` с `id=test`, а ищите `#test-link`?

Comment: мой косяк при создании вопроса, да, но даже если обозвать id так же как и в скрипте это ситуацию не поменяет, ее по прежнему не видно

Comment: Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь обратится к a до того, как элемент был встроен в DOM. Перенесите ваш селектор в функцию `renderHello`.

Comment: Точно, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае шаблонов, взаимодействие с DOM необходимо выполнять после того, как шаблон отрендерит элементы в DOM(Mustache или другой, не важно). 
Как один из вариантов, поиск элемента в DOM можно перенести в функцию renderHello().

```
let testLink = null;
function renderHello() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { name: 'Luke' });
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
  testLink = document.querySelector('#test-link');
  console.log(testLink)
}
```